# UBUNTU 20.04lts - No Sound through speakers but audible in headphones

Tags: 20.04

this is my alsa info - http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=9c6034c0ce6730533cce2cf4bdbab386d6df7c87

alsamixer shows all are unmuted and the sound graph is working fine but there is no sound
tried purging and reinstalling, still same output.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Check your output device selection in settings/sounds and then choose a device for the sound output.[sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEwXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using onboard sound port? If yes, is the model the Realteck ALC892? If yes, like me, you have a problem: seems Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu do not support this model. In my case, no onboard device showed at all in the settings manager. And, I had thunderous extremely loud, popping coming through my speakers.

The solution is to add 2 lines to the /modprobe.s/alsa-base.conf file, at the bottom...

options snd-hda-intel snoop=0 model=auto
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

Note: the model=auto should get your system to recognise the sound chip, but may not completely solve the settings issue. In my case, I must reset the default sound device after every boot to invoke surround 2.1.  Hope this helps.